# Django causing 403 forbidden error when i add csrf middleware

Tags: python, django, csrf-protection, django-csrf

When I add CSRF middleware `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to prevent xss csrf attack I am getting error response 403 csrf error.

- I referred to the official doc and old Stack Overflow answers but still I didn't get any idea why it causing error.
- I read from Django official doc if I added csrf middleware it will take care all csrf validation in every views by default.
- Along with this I have used some decorators too to ensure security like @login_required and @csrf_protect
- I have added `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` as a first entry before common middleware in Middleware class, is it because of that?

Comment: does this occur with a form?

Comment: submission , my app contains a button. when i submit button it occurred. @ThomasJiang

Comment: The [Django CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) cover how to use it. We can't help you because you haven't shown the full error, or the code (url/view/template) that triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

a form with CSRF in Django should look something like this:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
    {% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/)

Comment: Is it because of order ? 'csrf middleware'   class ? i have added as 1st entry in csrf clases(settings.py)